# TOTE: Desired vs perceived state = Fight or flight

Tags: motivation, behavior, task-analysis

A key concept in 1960s control theory is TOTE (Test-Operate-Test-Exit)<sup>1</sup>:

[image: A state diagram showing a first stage as test: "test nail", if it sticks up, the next operation is "hammer nail" going back to the "test nail" stage. If it is flush, exit]

The concept seems to be neatly mapped to a modern cognitive concept:

- The brain constantly compares perceived state to the normal state, if two do not match our attentive selection mechanism overshoots and consciousness is engaged.
- Similarly, when we formulate a plan, we constantly compare the perceived and desired state and take action to reach the desired state (fight), yet we may give up (flight).

My question: do recent cognitive theories supports this concept or are there competing models?

---

<sup>1</sup>Miller, G. a, Galanter, E., Pribram, K.H., 1960. *Plans and the Structure of Behavior*. Martino Fine Books, S.l.